# Scrapy CrawlSpider not functioning

Tags: python, scrapy

Not entirely sure what the issue is... I am following a tutorial and after looking over this for hours I cannot figure out what I'm missing.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from socrata.items import SocrataItem

class OpendataSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'opendata_crawl'
    allowed_domains = ['opendata.socrata.com']
    start_urls = ['https://opendata.socrata.com/']
    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow='browse\?utf8=%E2%9C%93&page\d*'),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        )
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info(f'Hi, this is an item page! {response.url}')
        titles = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="browse2-result"]')
        for title in titles:
            item = SocrataItem()
            item["text"] = title.xpath('.//div[@class="browse2-result-title"]/h2/a/text()').extract()[0]
            item["url"] = title.xpath('.//div[@class="browse2-result-title"]/h2/a/@href').extract()[0]
            item["views"] = title.xpath('.//div[@class="browse2-result-view-count-value"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            yield item
```

When this runs I get the following output:

```
2020-10-09 15:23:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-10-09 15:23:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-10-09 15:23:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-10-09 15:23:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://opendata.socrata.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-10-09 15:23:09 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-10-09 15:23:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://opendata.socrata.com/> (referer: None)
2020-10-09 15:23:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-10-09 15:23:22 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

I know the links work, I know the parsing method works,I don't quite know what is going wrong where but it seems like it quits before it tries any of the links and never triggers the parsing function.

Maybe it's the regex expression or maybe it's something about the way the code is set up?

Comment: There’s no `?utf8=%E2%9C%93&page` in that page.
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Turns out, they are on the page but the unicode character is no longer part of the links. Thank you for your help and for expanding my knowledge of scrapy with dynamic content. 

My eye kept skipping over the difference in the updated page. Sometimes I feel so dumb.